# Is there no way to use IB and the relationship of two entities to populate an OutlineView?

Tags: xcode, macos, core-data, interface-builder, nstreecontroller

I have touched on this question in others before but after writing an answer to a previous question there got me wondering why this isn't possible - or am I missing the fact that it might be?

Given that *Interface Builder* is very good at graphically linking various methods and delegates and data sources, is it possible that there's no straightforward graphical means to populate an `OutlineView` using two entities made in a `Core Data` model that have a parent child relationship set up so that (I believe)  there is enough information to define what parent nodes the child nodes would be listed under in the `outlineview`?

It confuses me as I see this as a very logical way of storing two distinct sources of information and later displaying their relationship. At the moment I am trying to work without using `NSTreeController`, using my own `datasource`, and edging into territory far beyond my current ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the silence to this question and the lack of results on google suggest this is not a built-in aspect of xcode. I hope it will be in future as all the information needed is in the child-parent relationship of the entities.

Until then I'm making my own class to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The `NSTreeController` is the supposed to be the controller for outlines but it's always had problems (granted I haven't used it recently.) People have often had to roll their own.

You need a tree controller or the equivalent because the outline view display isolated objects but instead indexpaths through an object graph. The outline doesn't really understand a parent->child relationships just an indexpath relation of say `1.1` or `1.2`.

If you can't get `NSTreeController` to work like you need, take a look at the class and write your own. For an outline you really do need something that provides an indexpath that the outline view understands.

Comment: Thanks for your comment TechZen. I should have explained a little bit better that I am using my own class (when I said I was using my own datasource other than NSTreeController).

Originally, I thought NSTreeController might have been able to implement the void I described above. I'm creating a class that combines two entities into an outlineview based on their parent relationship in core data. I'm just surprised that there was no in-built class in interfacebuilder to do this as it seems like such a common situation to find yourself in. I'm struggling with my attempt - but getting there slowly

Comment: Let me look at your previous question. I don't think I really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The past question isn't as relevant as I had thought. I basically wanted to see if there was some built-in controller to combine two entities into an `nsoutlineview` based on the child parent relationship of the entities. I believe the silence suggests that there isn't.